# Ajax подгрузка контента

Tags: php, ajax

Использую единую точку входа в index.php. Делаю загрузку хидера, футера и необходимого контента.
Я хочу изменять контент без перегрузки страницы - тут нужен ajax.
Но тут непонятно что с ссылками делать, href пустой, а при onclick происходит изменения контента (ajax).Как быть?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Попробуйте уточнить вопрос

Comment: @ДавидМанжула все запросы идут в index.php. Допустим при посещении syte/news -  происходит include header, news и footer. И так при каждом запросе. Мне нужно ajax добавить, чтобы обновлялся контент, а хидер и футер не менялись.

Comment: отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавив пример кода, который у вас есть и опишите как он работает сейчас, а как вы хотите, чтобы он работал

Answer (score -1):

Итак, смею предположить, у вас примерно такой index.php

```
$page = $_GET["path"]; // настраивается через .htaccess

include("header.php");

if(file_exists($page . ".php"){
  include($page . ".php");
}else{
  include("error.php");
}

include("footer.php");
```

Во-первых, при отправке AJAX нужно добавить заголовок `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. Этот заголовок значит что запрос посылается AJAXом и сервер должен это учитывать. jQuery добавляет его сам, на чистом js нужно будет самому добавить.

Теперь добавляем проверку на сервере:

```
$isAjax = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
$page = $_GET["path"];

if(!$isAjax){
  include("header.php");
}

if(file_exists($page . ".php"){
  include($page . ".php");
}else{
  include("error.php");
}

if(!$isAjax){
  include("footer.php");
}
```

Таким образом, если передать заголовок `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, сервер будет отдавать только контент страницы, без шапки и футера.